# Columns overwrite each other in HTML table

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have been using DreamWeaver for a number of years to build simple web sites and have never had any difficulty using tables to space out text on a page.

In my most recent project, I have created a 7 (row) by 2 (column) table inside a 1 x 1 table (the 1 x 1 contains a Photoshop-generated HTML slice as a background) into which I am aiming to enter a label (column 1) and associated information (column 2). When I look at the outcome in either DW Live View or a browser, the contents of column 2 are written over the top of column 1.

If I extract the code for the 7 x 2 table and paste it into a blank page it works fine.

I have uploaded the offending page to: http://www.onthepeninsula.biz/new/lucyscafe/index.html

The bottom row contains four columns (column two has been split into three cells for that row only. The content in column 2 & 3 have both been written into column 1.

**Link to page was wrong - should have been http://www.onthepeninsula.biz/new/lucyscafe/index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>On The Peninsula | Lucy's Cafe</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #2A599E;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
<link href="../otp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript">

<!--//BEGIN Script

function map(url) {

link =
window.open(url,"Link","toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=640,height=565,left=100,top=150");

}
//END Script-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('../images/buttons/home4.jpg','../images/buttons/name4.jpg','../images/buttons/category4.jpg','../images/buttons/pricing4.jpg','../images/buttons/join4.jpg','../images/buttons/contact4.jpg','../images/buttons/social4.jpg')">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (shop.psd) -->
<table width="719" height="280" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Table_01">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_01.jpg" width="1040" height="40" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="40" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="18">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_02.jpg" width="40" height="1000" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="heading.jpg" width="960" height="80" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="18">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_04.jpg" width="40" height="1000" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="80" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_05.jpg" width="960" height="31" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="31" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../index.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image42','','../images/buttons/home4.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/buttons/home3.jpg" alt="On The Peninsula Home" width="220" height="58" border="0" id="Image42"></a></td>
        <td rowspan="16">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_07.jpg" width="20" height="889" alt=""></td>
<td width="720" height="298" rowspan="6" align="left" valign="top" background="../images/shop/shop_08.jpg"><table width="720" height="290" border="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="700" height="280"border="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
        <td width="170" height="38">Business Name:</td>
        <td width="504" height="38">Lucy's Cafe</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="170" height="38">Address:</td>
        <td width="504" height="38">26 Talford Street, Mitchell Valley VIC 3999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="170" height="38">Telephone:</td>
        <td width="504" height="38">(03) 9999 9999</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="170" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="504" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="170" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="504" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="170" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="504" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="170" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="504" height="38">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr> 
</table></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="58" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../name.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image','','../images/buttons/name4.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/buttons/name3.jpg" alt="Browse by Business Name" width="220" height="60" border="0" id="Image"></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="60" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../category.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','../images/buttons/category4.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/buttons/category3.jpg" alt="Browse by Category" border="0" width="220" height="61" id="Image2"></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="61" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../pricing.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image3','','../images/buttons/pricing4.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/buttons/pricing3.jpg" alt="Pricing" border="0" width="220" height="59" id="Image3"></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_12.jpg" width="220" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../join.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image4','','../images/buttons/join4.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/buttons/join3.jpg" alt="Join On The Peninsula" width="220" height="59" border="0" id="Image4"></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_14.jpg" width="220" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_15.jpg" width="720" height="31" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><a href="../contact.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image5','','../images/buttons/contact4.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/buttons/contact3.jpg" alt="Contact On The Peninsula" border="0" width="220" height="59" id="Image5"></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="720" height="519" rowspan="6" valign="top" background="../images/shop/shop_17a.jpg"><table width="720" border="0" cellpadding="10">
          <tr>
            <td width="700"><p>This is an example of one of the business pages in On The Peninsula. </p>
            <p>The top section of each business page contains the important contact and location details for your business, including a link to a location map, if your business has a public-friendly workplace.</p>
            <p>Please note that this is an example page and that the email and web addresses listed above are not real - if you click on either, you'll be directed to the email address and Facebook page for On The Peninsula.</p>
            <p>In this section of the page, you have the opportunity to provide an overview of your business, what you do, what you sell, your trading hours - pretty much anything that you wish to tell a visitor to your site.</p>
            <p>You might be wondering about that black and white square on the bottom left corner of this page. This is called a Quick Response (or QR) code. These are very similar to a barcode and can be read by any one of several QR readers available for smartphones and tablets. These QR readers can be downloaded at no cost.</p>
            <p>The codes themselves can be linked to just about any piece of information - web addresses, contact cards, photos ... you name it. We have chosen to use them to create contact records in iPhones, Androids and any other device. We will link the QR code on your page to your contact details so that if someone scans the code on your page, your contact details will be saved on their device. Try it on this page and you'll find that our contact details get loaded into your phone!</p>
            <p>Finally, you'll notice that we are supporters of <a href="http://www.starlight.org.au" target="_blank">Starlight Children's Foundation</a> and you can be too. If you would like to have the Starlight Support's badge on your page, it will cost you $10 per year. Every dollar rasied via this process will be matched by us and donated directly to Starlight Children's Foundation.</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
          </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="29" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_18.jpg" width="220" height="1" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="../social.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image6','','../images/buttons/social4.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/buttons/social3.jpg" alt="Facebook & Twitter" width="220" height="60" border="0" id="Image6"></a></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="60" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_20.jpg" width="220" height="30" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_21.jpg" width="220" height="190" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="190" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_22.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="209" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_23.jpg" width="720" height="41" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="11" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/shop_24.jpg" width="220" height="30" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="../images/shop/spacer.gif" width="1" height="30" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It says "Page not Found". Post the offending code here for perusal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the stylesheet. Your `opt.css` file includes this:

```
#Table_01 tr td table tr td {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This sets all the `td` cells in your table to have absolute positioning. The position values aren't set, so they all end up at (0, 0) on top of each other.

Changing `position: absolute` to `position: relative` fixes it.

By the way, I found the problem using the developer tools in Chrome. There are similar tools for Firefox and Internet Explorer. It's worth learning how to use these so you can track down this sort of issue.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped. You might like to mark this as the selected answer by clicking on the tick if you're happy with it.